# What can I do to fix that Visual Studio won't display per file properties?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I went to go turn on precompiled headers in a brand new project, so I went to go create the "/Create" setting for precompiled headers. But the property page is blank.

[image: broken property page]

What happened, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Restarting visual studio doesn't work?

Comment: Yep. I even tried completely creating a new project (blowing away the existing one)

Comment: maybe you can try this: create a new empty solution/project. Copy source of an existing valid/good project to the empty project folder and add those to the project and see if the problem is still there. if it is do a file compare on the project-files of the new and the original project and see where there's a difference. if its not then I don't know any more suggestions.

Comment: @Edwin: As I said in my previous comment, this is in a brand new project. It's certainly not project related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a COM registration issue.  It's hard to tell what caused it but the best bet for fixing is to repair the Visual Studio install.  That should fix the issue.

- Go to Control Panel and run "Add / Remove Programs"
- Double click on "Visual Studio 2010 ..."
- Click Next on the installer
- Choose Repair / Reinstall
- Complete the Wizard

Comment: Oddly enough, the same dialog for the project works just fine; this only happens when I do per-file properties. Repairing now; will return with the results.

Comment: @BillyONeal That is odd indeed. Hopefully it is just a simple COM registration issue.

Comment: Hmm... could uninstalling SQL server management studio have done that? (Trying to think of anything VS related that's gotten removed lately on this box)

Comment: @BillyONeal that's a real bummer.  My next move would be to remove any plugin's I had and possibly reset my user registry hive for Visual Studio.

Comment: No idea what's going on. I'll probably just end up blowing away this VM and starting over :sigh:

Comment: @BillyONeal I'm struggling for a good answer here. The only other items I could think of are a bad entry in the .proj file, plugin, registry setting and resetting user settings. Repair should fix issues like this though.  It's puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across a similar issue (though I was using CMake to generate the project file), turns out it was [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/635294/using-absolute-path-in-clcompile-item-prevents-property-pages-from-showing) in VS2010. If you specify an absolute path for the source file in the project file, and it is on the same drive as the project file, then the property pages for that source file will not be visible. The suggested workaround is to create a new drive mapping for the drive where your source resides, and then to open the project from the mapped drive.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me this morning in my Visual Studio 2008, I read all the solutions in internet, I tried everything - reset setting, userdata, repair, uninstall and reinstall VS, but none solve my problem. I was almost going to reinstall the OS (Windows 10).

At last I found out after using a dir command in other project, AM/PM was replaced with strange words, it's because of my datetime format was changed (in my case, it was changed to Afar format). After reset to default, everything came back to normal.